# Java: Loading and Displaying XML

Tags: java

I am trying to write a java program that reads in an XML file and returns various elements of interest to the user.  I am having some issues getting it to compile and I have created a test class in order for it to be displayed properly.  This is what I have thus far.

EDIT: The Bolded Line in the test class is giving me problems.  The error is cannot convert from String to Resources.

```
public class T_Resources {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Resources resources = ResourceImporter.importResourcesFromXML("http://free1.ed.gov/xml/gemexport.xml");

    displayResources(resources);

}

private static void displayResources(Resources resources) {

    Subject[] subjects;

    **Resources resource = resources.getTitle();**

    System.out.println(resource.getTitle());

    System.out.println(resource.getDescription());

    System.out.println(resource.getIdentifier());

    subjects = resource.getSubjects();

    for (int i=0; i < subjects.length; ++i) {

        System.out.println(subjects[i].getCategory() + " :: " + subjects[i].getSubcategory());

    }

    System.out.println();
}

}

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ResourceImporter {

// This operation loads the XML document specified by the document location, which     can a file or a URL,
// and returns a reference to the document. If the operation cannot successfully load the document
// the operation returns the null reference.
//
private static Document loadXMLDocument(String documentLocation) {

    // The XML document.
    //
    Document documentIn     = null;

    // The parser that reads in an XML files.
    //
    DocumentBuilder parser  = null;

    // Pull the document
    //
    try {

        // Obtain a document parser.
        //
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        parser = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        documentIn = parser.parse(documentLocation);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException p) {

        System.out.println("Error creating parser.");
        System.out.println("   " + p.getMessage());

    } catch (SAXException s) {

        System.out.println("Document is not well formed.");
        System.out.println("   " + s.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException i) {

        System.out.println("Error accessing the file.");
        System.out.println("   " + i.getMessage());

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Unknown error occurred.");
        System.out.println("   " + e.getMessage());

    }


    return documentIn;

}

public static Resources importResourcesFromXML(String documentLocation) { 

    Resources resource = new Resources();

    Document doc;

    Element resourceElement;

    Element titleElement;
    String title;

    Element descriptionElement;
    String description;

    Element identifierElement;
    String identifiers;

    Element urlElement;
    String url;

    NodeList subjectList;

    Element subjectElement;
    String subjects;

    Element categoryElement;
    String category;

    Element subcategoryElement;
    String subcategory;


    doc = loadXMLDocument(documentLocation);

    resourceElement = (Element)doc.getElementsByTagName("resource").item(0);


    if (resourceElement != null) {

        titleElement = (Element)resourceElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0);  

        resource.setTitle( titleElement == null ? "unknown" : titleElement.getTextContent() );

        descriptionElement = (Element)resourceElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0);

        resource.setDescription( descriptionElement == null ? "unknown" : descriptionElement.getTextContent() );

        identifierElement = (Element)resourceElement.getElementsByTagName("identifier").item(0);


        if (identifierElement != null) {

            Identifier identifier = new Identifier();

            urlElement = (Element)identifierElement.getElementsByTagName("url").item(0);

            identifier.setURL( urlElement == null ? "unknown" : urlElement.getTextContent() );

            subjectElement = (Element)resourceElement.getElementsByTagName("subjects").item(0);

            if (subjectElement != null) {

                subjectList =     subjectElement.getElementsByTagName("subject");

                for (int i=0; i < subjectList.getLength(); ++i) {

                    Subject subject = new Subject();

                    subjectElement = (Element)subjectList.item(i);

                    categoryElement =     (Element)subjectElement.getElementsByTagName("category").item(0);

                    subject.setCategory( categoryElement == null ?     "unknown"  : categoryElement.getTextContent() );

                    subcategoryElement = (Element)subjectElement.getElementsByTagName("subcategory").item(0);

                    subject.setSubcategory( subcategoryElement == null ? "unknown" :subcategoryElement.getTextContent() );

                    resource.addSubject(subject);

                }
            }

        }
    }

    return resource;

}

}


public class Resources {

private static final int    MAX_SUBJECTS = 20;
private String              title;  
private String              description;
private Identifier          identifier;
private Subject[]           subjects;
private int                 subjectCount;


public Resources() {

    title           = "unknown title";
    description     = "unknown description";
    identifier      = null;

    subjects        = new Subject[MAX_SUBJECTS];
    subjectCount    = 0;

}

public void setTitle(String newTitle) {

    title = newTitle;

}

public String getTitle() {

    return title;

}

public void setDescription(String newDescription) {

    description = newDescription;

}

public String getDescription() {

    return description;

}

public void setIdentifier(Identifier newIdentifier) {

    identifier = newIdentifier;

}

public Identifier getIdentifier() {

    return identifier;

}

public void addSubject(Subject newSubject) {

    subjects[subjectCount++] = newSubject;

}

public Subject[] getSubjects() {

    Subject[] result = new Subject[subjectCount];

    System.arraycopy(subjects, 0, result, 0, subjectCount);

    return result;
}

}



public class Subject {

private String category;
private String subcategory;

public Subject() {

    String category         = "unknown";
    String subcategory      = "unknown";

}

public Subject(Subject subject) {

    category        = subject.category;
    subcategory     = subject.subcategory;

}

public void setCategory(String newCategory) {

    category = (newCategory == null) ? "unknown" : newCategory;

}

public String getCategory() {

    return category;

}

public void setSubcategory(String newSubcategory) {

    subcategory = newSubcategory;

}

public String getSubcategory() {

    return subcategory;

}
}


public class Identifier {

private String url;

public Identifier() {

    url = "unknown";

}

public void setURL(String newURL) {

    url = newURL;

}

public String getURL() {

    return url;

}

}
```

Comment: What is the error?  What line is it on?  Nobody is going to sift through screens full of code.  Prepare to get downvotes w/o some clean up.

Comment: My apologies.  I bolded the line in the Test Class that is giving me issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The error lies in here:

```
private static void displayResources(Resources resources) {

    Subject[] subjects;

    // DELETE THIS
    // **Resources resource = resources.getTitle();**


    // RENAME 'resource' to 'resources', or just change the method parameter above...
    System.out.println(resources.getTitle());
    //System.out.println(resource.getTitle());

    System.out.println(resources.getDescription());
    //System.out.println(resource.getDescription());

    System.out.println(resources.getIdentifier());
    //System.out.println(resource.getIdentifier());

   ....
```

You pass a Resources Object, and normally you would want to work directly with it? 
Currently this just seems borked here, all the other code works, I tested and get fancy console outputs.

## EDIT: (Answering a comment below this post.)

In `ResourceImporter.java` add line following the comment below:

```
if (resourceElement != null) {

        titleElement = (Element)resourceElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0);  

        resource.setTitle( titleElement == null ? "unknown" : titleElement.getTextContent() );

        descriptionElement = (Element)resourceElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0);

        resource.setDescription( descriptionElement == null ? "unknown" : descriptionElement.getTextContent() );

        identifierElement = (Element)resourceElement.getElementsByTagName("identifier").item(0);


        if (identifierElement != null) {

            Identifier identifier = new Identifier();

            urlElement = (Element)identifierElement.getElementsByTagName("url").item(0);

            identifier.setURL( urlElement == null ? "unknown" : urlElement.getTextContent() );
            
            // ADDED THIS LINE HERE
            resource.setIdentifier(identifier);

            subjectElement = (Element)resourceElement.getElementsByTagName("subjects").item(0);

            if (subjectElement != null) {

                subjectList =     subjectElement.getElementsByTagName("subject");

            ....
```

You may also want to use this line for your syso's in the helper method being used in the main method: `System.out.println(resources.getIdentifier().getURL());`, otherwise you will get uninterpretable information.

Comment: Yeah that seems to do it.  I am getting one Resource as output but I am trying to get all the Resources from that XML file so I think I need to change the importer class to an array.

Comment: @user2604892 then be happy and accept the answer. Once you get the Resources passed as an array, use a foreach loop (or just a regular for loop, if you prefer to avoid using the Iterable), for your getting all your printlines... :)

Comment: How would I get the URL in?  My getIdentifier line isn't working like the rest and instead need to getURL.

Comment: Thanks for the edit that helped explain a lot.  I wanted to change all my arrays in Resources and T_Resources to an arraylist so I don't have to worry about managing.  I also need to get this method:

public static Resources importResourcesFromXML(String documentLocation)
to accept an arraylist as well, any input for me on that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd change

```
private static void displayResources(Resources resources)
```

to

```
private static void displayResources(Resources resource)
```

(notice I removed the 's'), and remove your bold line.

As stated by JB Nizet, your method returns a String when you want the Resources that is passed to your static  method.

Comment: Yeah, that seemed to be my problem! I get a resource as output now, I just need to figure out how to get ALL the resources in.  I guess I need to change something to an array or a list.  The getIdentifier isn't working, I need to get the URL in.

Comment: Use List<Resources> if you can, and iterate over it would be the best. (Element)doc.getElementsByTagName() will return such a list.

Comment: Where would I put List<Resources>?

 public static Resources importResourcesFromXML(String documentLocation)?

Comment: Read the doc and do some thinking yourself, we're not here to work for you, just giving hint or share experience.
That said, I would change `public static Resources importResourcesFromXML(String)` to `public static List<Resources> importResourcesFromXML(String)` and inside that function, replace `resourceElement = (Element)doc.getElementsByTagName("resource").item(0);` by a `for` loop: `NodeList lst = (Element)doc.getElementsByTagName("resource");` then `for (int i = 0; i < lst.getLength(); i++) { resourceElement = (Element)doc.getElementsByTagName("resource").item(i); ... }`

Comment: Just looking for guidance not for answers.  I like to put the time in until I hit a wall.  With the addition of the arraylist I can get rid of statements like these correct?
//resource.setTitle( titleElement == null ? "unknown" : titleElement.getTextContent() );

having issues with this statement resource.setIdentifier(identifier);

which I am sure its just a syntax issue with the arraylist

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point. What kind of "issue" are you referring to with the `setIdentifier()` statement? A `List` is just a container of several, same-typed objects. You can't call a method on a list that will call it on all of its elements without a (simple) `for` loop.
A general statement to your code would be to check that you actually have enough objects before calling `.item(0)`. If the `getElemensByTagName()` returns `null`, you'll get a `NPE`.

Answer (score 0):

The getTitle() method is declared as

```
public String getTitle()
```

But you're assigning its result to a variabe of type Resources:

```
Resources resource = resources.getTitle();
```

That obviously can't work, hence the error, which is quite self-explanatory:

> cannot convert from String to Resources

You probably want

```
 String title = resources.getTitle();
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I have tried making that change but it seems to then cause errors with the rest of my statements like: System.out.println(resource.getTitle()); which says the method getTitle is undefined for type String.

Comment: then I think just say `Resources resource = resources;`... and then continue